# how to fix range within a form

Tags: html, css

I made a form with five options to order books. Every option is a different input type itself. The problem is that each rule doesn't stay inline. The contact form also moves to right. It should look like example 1. what went wrong with my code? please see my complete code atached.

Thanks

```
<p><label for="range">Katheryn Stockett - The Help:</label></p>
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="15" step="5" list="range-lijst">
    <datalist id="boeken">
        <option value="0" label="0">
        <option value="5">
        <option value="10" label="10">
        <option value="15">
  </datalist>
<small>Bestel 0,5,10 of 15 exemplaren</small>
```

all options should stay inline.

[image]

```css
body  {
    background-color:oldlace; 
}

.bg { 
    height: 100%; 
}

 form button#submit 
{
text-align: center;
margin: 4px;
display:inline;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 55px;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px #888888;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.leftFloated{
  float:left;
}

label{
    width: 480px;
    display: inline-block
}

input[type="radio"] {
        margin-left: 10px;
        display: inline
        }
```

```html
<h1>Boeken bestellen</h1>
      <p>Op deze pagina kunt u snel en gemakkelijk uw favoriete boeken bestellen die in de top 5 staan. U kunt per boek aangeven hoeveel u er van wilt bestellen. Let wel op dat bepaalde boeken beperkt beschikbaar zijn. Dit is aangegeven bij het boek.</p>
      <h2> Bestel hier uw boeken</h2>
      <p><label for="schrijver">Khaled Hosseini - A Thousand Splendid Suns:
      <input id="schrijver" name="aantal boeken" type="number" value="0" min="1" max="10"> <small> max. 10 exemplaren</small>
      </label></p>
       <br>
       <br>
      <p><label for="auteur">Paulo Coelho - The Alchemist:
      <input id="auteur" name="boeken" type="number" value="0" min="1" max="99"><small> max. 99 exemplaren</small>
      </label></p>
       <br>
    
       <p><label for="range">Katheryn Stockett - The Help:</label></p>
      <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="15" step="5" list="range-lijst">
      <datalist id="boeken">
         <option value="0" label="0">
         <option value="5">
         <option value="10" label="10">
         <option value="15">
      </datalist>
      <small>Bestel 0,5,10 of 15 exemplaren</small>
      <p><label>Miguel de Cervantes - Don Quixote</label>            
      <input type = "radio"
         name = "radSize"
         id = "5"
         value = "1" />
      <label for = "5">5</label>
      <input type = "radio"
         name = "radSize"
         id = "10"
         value = "10" />
      <label for = "10">10</label>
      <input type = "radio"
         name = "radSize"
         id = "20"
         value = "20" />
      <label for = "20">20</label></p>       
      <p>Khaled Hosseini - The Kite Runner</p>
      <select name="aantal boeken">
      <option value="geen">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
      </div>
      <h2>Geef hier uw adresgegevens op</h2>
      <div class="container">
         <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
            <div>
               <label for="naam">Naam:</label>
               <input type="text" id="naam"> 
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="adres">Adres:</label>
               <input type="text" id="adres">
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="pc3">Postcode:</label>
               <input id="pc3" pattern="[0-9] {4}\s[A-Z]{2}" title="Een postcode bestaat uit 4 cijfers, 1 spatie en 2 hoofdletters" placeholder="1111 AA">
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="woonplaats">Woonplaats:</label>
               <input type="text" id="woonplaats">
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
               <input type="text" id="email">
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="leverdatum">leverdatum:</label>
               <input type="date" id="leverdatum">
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="bestand">Bestand:</label>
               <input type="file" id="bestand">
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your label has `480px` width. It prevents your inputs to stay in one line with their label. Change their properties like:

```
label /* If you want to set this style only on range inputs you should change it to label[for=range]*/ {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 1em 0 0;
}

input[type=radio],
input.radio {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
```

And if you want to keep form in left and button in right, you should [wrap](https://css-tricks.com/best-way-implement-wrapper-css/) form in one div and button in another div and set their with in persent, and then wrap both divs in another div like below.

```css
.content-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.form-wrapper, .button-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
 <div class="form-wrapper">
    <h2> Bestel hier uw boeken</h2>
    <p><label for="schrijver">Khaled Hosseini - A Thousand Splendid Suns:
    <input id="schrijver" name="aantal boeken" type="number" value="0" min="1" max="10"> <small> max. 10 exemplaren</small>
    </label></p>
     <br>
     <br>
    <p><label for="auteur">Paulo Coelho - The Alchemist:
    <input id="auteur" name="boeken" type="number" value="0" min="1" max="99"><small> max. 99 exemplaren</small>
    </label></p>
     <br>
     <p><label for="range">Katheryn Stockett - The Help:</label></p>
    <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="15" step="5" list="range-lijst">
    <datalist id="boeken">
    <option value="0" label="0">
    <option value="5">
    <option value="10" label="10">
    <option value="15">
    </datalist>
    <small>Bestel 0,5,10 of 15 exemplaren</small>
    <p><label>Miguel de Cervantes - Don Quixote</label>
    <input type = "radio"
    name = "radSize"
    id = "5"
    value = "1" >
    <label for = "5">5</label>
    <input type = "radio"
    name = "radSize"
    id = "10"
    value = "10" >
    <label for = "10">10</label>
    <input type = "radio"
    name = "radSize"
    id = "20"
    value = "20" >
    <label for = "20">20</label></p>       
    <p>Khaled Hosseini - The Kite Runner</p>
    <select name="aantal boeken">
     <option value="geen">0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="button-wrapper">
  <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the html structure is different for each section that you want to be styled the same. To keep things consistent and eliminate potential issues, try using the same structure for each block. Looking at that, will fix that issue.

The structure below was used for one item:

```
    <p>
        <label for="auteur">Paulo Coelho - The Alchemist:
            <input id="auteur" name="boeken" type="number" value="0" min="1" max="99">
            <small> max. 99 exemplaren</small>
        </label>
    </p>
```

yet, another section looked different like this:

```
    <p>Khaled Hosseini - The Kite Runner</p>
    <select name="aantal boeken">
        <option value="geen">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```

Adapting the second block of code to mirror the structure of the second block fixes that layout issue, like so:

```
    <p>
        <label>
            Khaled Hosseini - The Kite Runner</p>
            <select name="aantal boeken">
                <option value="geen">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
```

In terms of the placement of your button, you have two options to place it to the right. The first is to absolute position it which can get tricky, or you have to visualize that there is content on the left in it's own container with `float: left;`, and the button is in it's own container with `float: right;`. This would look like this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="float-left">
            <!-- form content here -->
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <!-- form button here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

You would set then need to adjust the widths on the `float-left` and `float-right` class, and be sure to clear the floats on the container.

Comment: Yeah, it looks confusing but I have use five different structures (range, radio buttons etc). Thank you, I can use this to adjust my code.

Comment: I'm also struggling with placing all the text/boxes right under eacht other like the example.